# selenium con python para recuparar info de vehiculos de ocasion, aparece div habilitado para aceptar datos de privacidad

Tags: html, python, selenium, print

estoy intentando recuperar con python a través de selenium, info de vehiculos de ocasion y cada vez que acceso a coches.net/segunda-mano o me aparece la pantalla con un div habilitado para aceptar datos de privacidad o me aparece una pantalla distinta con el siguiente  titulo: Ups! Parece que algo no va bien...
Entiendo que cuando sale la otra pantalla, la de Ups!... es porque el servidor detecta que se trata de un bot. pero cuando aparece la pagina del portal con el div habilitado indicando los datos de privacidad no se como simular que estoy pulsando el boton Aceptar...
Pueden ayudarme?

Este es el código que tengo:

```
introducir el código aquí

from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument ("--user_agent:{...}")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = './chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

driver.get ("www.coches.net/segunda-mano/")
if (driver.getTitle() == "Ups...!"):
    print("pagina web erronea")
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
else:
    #aqui recupera la pagina pero con el div de aceptacion de datos privados

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Por favor, para poder ayudarte debes poner el código como estas haciendo, de otro modo parecería que quieres que te hagan el script completo.

Comment: hecho......................................................................

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente está detectando que eres un *bot*. En ese caso, utiliza el paquete *undetected-chromedriver* que pasa desapercibido a los servicios anti-bot. Lo puedes instalar:

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver
```

Como *undetected-chromedriver* es un parche del Chrome driver, lo utilizas como si se tratara de este último:

```
#from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
#from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from time import sleep
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

#chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
# Colocar las opciones equivalentes de acuerdo a la versión de Chrome que utilizas
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")


try:
    print("Invocando página")
#    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
#    driver = uc.Chrome(driver_executable_path = './chromedriver',options=chrome_options,headless=True)
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options,headless=True)
    driver.get("https://www.coches.net/segunda-mano/")

    dlgPrivacidadSelector = ".sui-MoleculeModal-dialog.sui-MoleculeModal-dialog--fit .sui-TcfFirstLayer-title"
    try:
        
        dlgPrv = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,dlgPrivacidadSelector);
        btn=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid="TcfAccept"]')
        print("Dialogo de Privacidad click en aceptar")
        btn.click()
        print("Dialogo de Privacidad cerrado")
    except:
        pass

    print(driver.page_source)
    print(driver.title)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception {e}")    
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


No olvides de incluir: *from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By*. En este ejemplo he utilizado *By.CSS_SELECTOR* pero puedes utilizar otro como *By.ID* solo tienes que identificar que dato es el mas adecuado que identifique al boton "aceptar" de la ventana.
```

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, mil gracias por tu tu dedcacion y rapida respuesta. He probado tu solucion y el resultado del codigo html lo he pasado a fichero y esta recuperando esta pagina con este titulo:
<title>Ups! Parece que algo no va bien...</title>

Esta este es el código
try:
  print("Invocando página")
  driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options,headless=True)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  driver.get(WEB)
  paginaWeb = driver.page_source
  traceo_en_fichero(paginaWeb)
  print(driver.page_source)
except Exception as e:
  print(f"Exception {e}")    
finally:
  ....

Comment: Que raro, lo acabo de probar y funciona bien, me trae la página correcta. Con el WebDriver de Chrome si me sale la pagina de Ups pero con el undetected-chrome me funciona bien.

Comment: Acabo de probar con el código que me pones en tu comentario (con linea de trace0 comentada) y funciona me trae la página.

Comment: Esto es parte de la página que me trae: *MoleculeDropdownOption-text sui-MoleculeDropdownOption-text--noWrap">NISSAN</span></li><li tabindex="0" class="sui-MoleculeDropdownOption" role="option" data-value="32" aria-label="32" aria-checked="false"><span class="sui-MoleculeDropdownOption-text sui-MoleculeDropdownOption-text--noWrap">OPEL</span></li><li tabindex="0" class="sui-MoleculeDropdownOption" role="option" data-value="33" aria-label="33" aria-checked="false"><span class="sui-MoleculeDropdownOption-text sui-MoleculeDropdownOption-text--noWrap">PEUGEOT*

Comment: No pude contestar antes, lanzando tu codigo muestra la pantalla principal con div activo para aceptar privacidad de datos.El codigo html donde aparecen el boton q tengo que pulsar es 'Aceptar y Cerrar':
<button data-testid="TcfConfig" class="sui-AtomButton sui-AtomButton--primary sui-AtomButton--outline sui-AtomButton--center"><span class="sui-AtomButton-inner">Configurar</span></button><button data-testid="TcfAccept" class="sui-AtomButton sui-AtomButton--primary sui-AtomButton--solid sui-AtomButton--center"><span class="sui-AtomButton-inner">Aceptar y cerrar</span></button>

Comment: Como llamo a ese boton para que realice la accion de pulsar el boton? he probado esto pero no va:
boton = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//button[@class='sui-AtomButton sui-AtomButton--primary sui-AtomButton--solid sui-AtomButton--center']")[0]
boton.click()

Comment: Por otro lado, como estoy realizando pruebas/error, a la quinta vez que pruebo el servidor detecta que se trata de un bot y muestra la pantalla con titulo: Ups! Parece que algo no va bien...
Como puedo corregir esto para que pueda hacer mis pruebas sin que me detecte el servidor.

Comment: Si te sale un modal con datos de.privacidad, entonces, no creo que estés yendo hacia, www.coches.net/segunda-mano/. Hay algo que no cuadra o.no estas.mencionando

Comment: Generalmente las pantallas para aceptar datos de privacidad aparecen cuando estas de una u otra forma registrando algunos información sobre ti. Por lo tanto no creo que estés yendo directamente hacia www.coches.net/segunda-mano/ sino hacia una URL debajo de esta.

Comment: Hola, está claro q la página se mueve por cookies. Cómo no tengo la cookie q hace falta pues se activa el div de privacidad. La prueba está en q si borro las cookies y entro al navégador y pongo la ruta me pasa exactamente lo mismo, se activa el div de privacidad.    Y al pulsar botón Aceptar y cerrar se oculta el div y ya no vuelve a aparecer en sucesivas consultas. A diferencia de q si lo hago desde programa Python siempre arranca el navegador limpio y por eso siempre me aparece el div de privacidad habilitado.

Comment: Probaré como me dices y veo si te doy una solución

Comment: Hasta que me salió la bendita página de privacidad. He actualizado la respuesta para darle clic al boton aceptar.